# How to include log4j.properties with mvn assembly:assembly?

Tags: java, maven-2, log4j

I want to include a log4j into the package generated by `mvn assembly:assembly` so that log4j is configured when the generated `.jar` is executed. How do I do this?

My assembly plugin looks like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>ibis.structure.Structure</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I think that providing some details about your project structure and the current content of your assembly descriptor would help.

Comment: What do you mean by "log4j is configured when the generated .jar is executed"? I would guess that what you need is to include the log4j.properties in the .jar??

Comment: Yes, I need to include log4j.properties in the .jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to include a log4j into the package generated by mvn assembly:assembly so that log4j is configured when the generated .jar is executed. How do I do this?

I don't understand the problem. Put the `log4j.properties` under `src/main/resources` and it will be packaged in your jar (and then end up in the assembly). Is there any problem with that?

Comment: Putting my log4j.properties file under src/main/resources and rebuilding did Not result in the file being included. Is there more that needs to be done?

Comment: What is in your resources section?  You have to include the .properties files.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend packaging log4j descriptor into a jar otherwise you can't change any log level without repackaging, which could be a pain. Better externalizing your log4j.properties into a directory on your file system that you include in the classpath.